# Saving External Resources (large file size)

Tags: ios, image

I have more than 1000 pictures and audio files, which are about 30G in total.  If I put them in Xcode resources, the app will be very large.  Where can I put them? And how can I get them in Xcode?

Comment: 30G? I guess you could save them in photo library and access them from there, same with audio files from music library. Of course you'd have to synch all these from iTunes or something. Couldn't you access them dynamically from web?

Answer (score 0):

For such a large amount of media, most optimal compression is something you can't overlook.

Some ideas:

- use jpegs with maximum acceptable compression that works best for the app
- cut unnecessary resolution (ex. max 640x960 for retina devices)
- compress audio as much as you can (cut sample rate, use different format, etc)
- store some portion on a web-server, bundle some media with the app, so it can be started quickly, then have user download images/sounds in the background, on a per-screen basis...